# Sharepoint 2010 how to change infopath view in sharepoint for filling

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-addin, database, xml, infopath-data-connections

I have 2 separate departments updating one SharePoint library list
instead of changing the view in the InfoPath form itself for each department
can I change it by creating a link in the SharePoint quick launch to change the view before opening the InfoPath form?.

if you have a better suggestion for this idea please let me know.
dept A can update the SharePoint custom library
dept B can update the same SharePoint custom library but different fill upform.

I'm planning to create a quick launch sepe

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, You are trying to create two separate views for two departments, And you wish to open the default view based on the department that is opening the form. And later you wish to submit the form to a single document library.

Yes, this can be done by creating two different links for each department and in the source URL we need to add an attribute **"&defaultView = "**. So this opens up that view required for that department.

Comment: are you pertaining to the infopath views?

Comment: Yes. Create 2 views first in infopath. and then we need to create 2 links